# Google Maps not showing on phone

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My Manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <application android:label="Pelican" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="MyKey" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
    </application>
```

Map showing on emulator in Debug

[image]

But not showing on phone in Release

[image]

What could be the reason?

Comment: Don't post code as image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the API key. The key was for Debug config.So for Release he not worked.

Comment: Please do not forget the mark your answer, it will help others who have similar issue,

Answer (score 3):

check that you given permission to access the map.